# memory allocation and getline

Tags: c, file, pointers, getline

I don't understand in this code why there is no malloc for the *line pointer, does getline dynamically allocate memory? is it mendatory for a pointer to be pointing to NULL if it's not pointing to a memory adress?
I see `getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1` what is the the return value of a getline if the operation is done correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE    *   fp;             // file pointer
    char    *   line = NULL;
    int         len  = 0;

int cnt = 0;    

if( argc < 3)
{
    printf("Insufficient Arguments!!!\n");
    printf("Please use \"program-name file-name N\" format.\n");
    return -1;
}

// open file
fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

// checking for file is exist or not
if( fp == NULL )
{
    printf("\n%s file can not be opened !!!\n",argv[1]);
    return 1;   
}

// read lines from file one by one
while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1)
{
    cnt++;
    if ( cnt > atoi(argv[2]) )
        break;

    printf("%s",line); fflush(stdout);
}

// close file
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to this declaration

```
char    *   line = NULL;
```

So initially the pointer value is `NULL`. Nowhere in main the pointer is explicitly reassigned.

On the other hand look at this call

```
getline(&line, &len, fp)
```

As it is seen the pointer line is passed to the function by reference. It means that within the function the pointer can be changed and a new value can be assigned to the pointer.

So if initially the pointer was equal to NULL then the pointer can be reassigned in the function in two ways.

The first one is when the function has a local array with the static storage duration and the pointer is assigned by the address of the first element of the array. But thjis approach is not flexible.

The second approach is when the function reallocates the memory pointed to by the pointer dynamically.

In the last case you have to free the allocated memory pointed to by the pointer line in main  when it is not required anymore.

Also you could read the description of the function where is explicitly said that the function allocates dynamically memory address of which is assigned to the pointer.

For example in man-pages for Linux there is written

```
   If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
   getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
   should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

   Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a
   pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the
   buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it
   with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.

   In either case, on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated
   to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

> ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
>
> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
>          getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>          should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.
>
> Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a
>          pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the
>          buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it
>          with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.
>
> In either case, on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated
>          to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.

So, `getline` will allocate the memory if you pass a `NULL` pointer and a `len` of 0 to it. Future calls inside the loop will not allocate fresh memory but use the same address. `realloc` is called if the length is not sufficient.

Also, you should free the `line` at the end as a good practice. This free should be called even if the `getline` has returned `-1`